# Call Receiver's voice is not recording

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-mediarecorder, call-recording

Hi I am making call recorder application. In my app I am allowing user to record call. and then recording will be saved in directory. But right now I am facing one issue in my application. after making call if I check in saved recordings, only my voice is I can listen, call receiver's voice is not recording. can any one help me to solve this issue?

```
public class RecorderService extends Service {

    MediaRecorder recorder;
    static final String TAGS=" Inside Service";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId)
    {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.reset();

        String phoneNumber=intent.getStringExtra("number");
        Log.d(TAGS, "Phone number in service: "+phoneNumber);

        String time=new CommonMethods().getTIme();

        String path=new CommonMethods().getPath();

        String rec=path+"/"+phoneNumber+"_"+time+".mp4";

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

        recorder.setOutputFile(rec);

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();

        Log.d(TAGS, "onStartCommand: "+"Recording started");

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder=null;

        Log.d(TAGS, "onDestroy: "+"Recording stopped");

    }
}
```

Comment: `AudioSource.CAMCORDER` will use one or more of the device's internal microphones, so that won't pick up the voice call downlink audio. The correct audio source is `AudioSource.VOICE_CALL`, but this requires a permission which 3rd party apps no longer can get.

Comment: @Michael then what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: The way I see it, 3rd party apps are no longer allowed to record voice call downlink audio. Maybe you can find some hack that works on some specific devices and Android versions, but other than that I don't really see any solution.